# Stop and restart kubernetes nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I have four nodes

`kubectl get nodes`

```
NAME            STATUS     AGE
adm-1   Ready      42s
adm-2   Ready      42s
adm-3   Ready      42s
```

So I want to stop these nodes temporarily, then restart them again

Note-This is not a GKE cluster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

A node can also be marked as unschedulable and drained manually. Without going into specifics, this is done with the following `kubectl` commands.

`kubectl cordon <node>` # marks the node as unschedulable (but doesn’t do anything with pods running on that node).

`kubectl drain <node>` # marks the node as unschedulable and then evicts all the pods from the node.

So try `drain` options in your case.

**Note:** In both cases, no new pods are scheduled to the node until you `uncordon` it again with `kubectl uncordon <node>`.